# Click button unresponsive

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

So recently I started learning cypress, and I started automating this e-commerce website called flipkart.

So firstly I have started by testing the add to cart option.

```
describe('flipkart', () => {
    it.only('0-500', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.flipkart.com/')
        cy.get('._3704LK').type('Watches')
        cy.get('.L0Z3Pu > svg').click()
        cy.get('select').last().select('500')
        cy.wait(1000)
        cy.get('._5THWM1 > :nth-child(5)').click()
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > ._13oc-S')    
        cy.wait(1000)
        cy.get('img').eq(14).wait(1000).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
            .should('have.attr', 'href').then((href) => {
                cy.visit(`https://www.flipkart.com${href}`)
            })    
        cy.wait(1000)    
        cy.get('button[class="_2KpZ6l _2U9uOA _3v1-ww"]')
        .contains("ADD TO CART")
        .click()
        
    })
})
```

Now whenever It clicks on the Add to cart it's unresponsive. I tried various ways like asked
by a few who faced similar problem , like `{force:true}` and also `trigger('click')`.
But it was still unsuccessful.
It would be nice if someone could help me out.
Thank you.

Here is a snapshot.
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MMus.png)
[snapshot html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaKYY.png)

Comment: Maybe your jquery element doens't contain the click event. It's too hard to tell without some html to show.

Comment: I'll take a snapshot of the html code

Comment: The click event may not be binded to the button yet. You could benefit from adding assertions instead of having hardcoded waits.

Comment: It's like when I code it to click it's unresponsive but when I manually click it in the cypress browser it works.